# angularJS: naming conventions on getter and setter methods with cached data

Tags: angularjs, naming-conventions

I'm having trouble naming my service functions, this is the situation:

I have the `data` object that stores all data coming from an API. I need a set function that GET's the data from the api and SETs the `data` object in this service. I need a GET function that returns said `data` object.
And finally there is the SET function that saves new data coming from the service consumer (e.g. a controller) to my `data` object and sets off a POST/PUT to the API.

```
function dataService() {

    var data = {};

    var service = {
        get: function() {
            return data;
        },
        setOrGet: function() {

            // GET schema from API and .then
            data = apiResponse;

        },
        set: function(newData) {
            data = newData;
            // PUT new data to API
        }
    }

}
```

I don't know how to name the `setOrget` function because technically it sets the `data` object but it `GET`s the data from the API. The Service of course has the regular `set` and `get` function as well.

Is there a recommended naming approach?

Comment: How about `getDataFromApi`? It kind of implies that it 'sets' or 'saves' the fetched data to your service.

Comment: I'd probably call it `reload`.

Comment: @Fissio that's what I'm currently leaning towards, just wanted to know if there are already some conventions when data is cached (as in: `GET` isn't always setting up a new API call

Comment: @muenchdo I was at that point too until I found it weird to call `service.reload()` in initiation (that data will only be `GET` once mostly)